# Cert not yet due for renewal ... but it's expired

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am trying to renew a wildcard `let's encrypt` certificate.

```
/usr/local/bin/certbot renew


Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/sub.myDomain.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.myDomain.com/fullchain.pem expires on 2019-08-14 (skipped)
No renewals were attempted.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

It responds that `Cert not yet due for renewal`.
But actually it has expired:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect sub.myDomain.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
notBefore=Mar 11 15:32:13 2019 GMT
notAfter=Jun  9 15:32:13 2019 GMT
```

How do I renew it?
Here is how I created that certificate:

```
certbot certonly \
          --dns-google \
          --email myEmail@gmail.com \
          --agree-tos \
          -d *.sub.myDomain.com
```

Comment: Was your web server restarted after renewing the cert?

Comment: no it wasn’t, it’s docker container, I’ll try to restart it

Comment: @Sven you are right, reloading nginx helped me, so the correct way to renew is: `/usr/local/bin/certbot renew --post-hook '/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload'`

Answer (score 6):

Your system renewed its certificate last month, but the web server never restarted or reloaded to actually start using it.

To fix the problem, reload/restart the web server.

You can also supply the appropriate command to reload your web server as a `--deploy-hook` to your `certbot renew` command.